# Is there a way to make a whole match optional?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a complex query with multiple 'with' clauses. I need one of the matches to be entirely optional. For example:

```
m-[:LOVES]->f-[:FATHERED]->d-[:SISTER_OF]-s collect(d) as daughters
```

I would need d to be returned only if all the other relationships were true, but to have the possibility of daughters being empty. Right now, without any part of it being optional, my whole query returns empty.

Comment: any way you can set up a (small) example data set on http://console.neo4j.org?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
m-[:LOVES]->f-[:FATHERED]->d-[?:SISTER_OF]-s collect(d) as daughters
```

Which would return null for `s` if not matched.

In general I would separate the two matches though:

```
MATCH m-[:LOVES]->f-[:FATHERED]->d
WITH DISTINCT d
MATCH d-[?:SISTER_OF]-s 
RETURN collect(d) as daughters
```